# Prepend/Append words to slug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get pretty links with Laravel.

I have posts with tags. My tagged posts are viewable via `localhost/tag-slug`. I store tags slugs in database.

I'm trying to append and prepend these slugs with some words so I can have something like:

- `localhost/awesome-laravel-posts`
- `localhost/best-php-posts`

I can get it to work with:

```
Route::get('/awesome-{tag}-posts', 'TagsController@index')->name('tag')
```

But when the tag slug contains a `-`, it fails.

Here is my model:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course u can do tha. I recommend dedicated library for example Eloquent Sluggable: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

Installation:

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable:^4.3
```

Usage:

```
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Easy creation of slugs for your Eloquent models in Laravel.

Comment: this is not what he asked. he is not asking how to create a slug, but how to append/prepend a string to a slug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to define route arguments. You could do this and {tag} will match anything:

```
Route::get('/awesome-{tag}-posts', 'TagsController@index')
    ->where('tag', '.*')->name('tag');
```

You could probably write a better regex for your case.